# Show certain content if a pound sign shows anywhere on the web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have created the below to look for a flag on our website and display a message if certain country flags show on our website.

I am wanting to adapt this though to show message below UNLESS a pound sign (£) shows anywhere on the page. How would I do this? Many thanks

```
<p id="checkout_notification_text" style="display:none;margin-top:-7px;"><b>As you are viewing prices in a currency other than GBP, prices shown will be converted into GBP by your card processor. This card processor <i>may</i> add a currency conversion fee of up to 2.5%.</b></p>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var flg =readCookie("currencyflag");
    if (!flg) {
             $("dl.CurrencyList").children().eq(0).find("img").each(function(){
                flg =$(this).attr("src"); 
             });
     }
    if(flg) {
        var flgImgArray = flg.split("/");
        var flgImg = flgImgArray[flgImgArray.length-1]; 

        if(flgImg != 'gb.gif'){
           $('#checkout_notification_text').show();
        }else{
           $('#checkout_notification_text').hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

CODE I AM NOW ON:

```
<p id="checkout_notification_text" style="display:none;margin-top:-7px;"><b>As you are viewing prices in a currency other than GBP, prices shown will be converted into GBP by your card processor. This card processor <i>may</i> add a currency conversion fee of up to 2.5%.</b></p>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
if ($("body:contains('£')").length) {
 $('#checkout_notification_text').hide();
} else {
//it is not found
}
 </script>
```

Comment: If I'm reading this right, it isn't actually searching the page for any occurence anyway: `flg` will be over-written each time around the `.each` looping construct, so will be the `src` URL of the last `img` in the first child out of any `dl` elements with class `CurrencyList`.

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you for your reply. If you wouldn't mind seeing the comment I made below, it may resolve the confusion. The working code above was just my starting point. The new code I am wanting is irrelevant of flags and purely based on whether the web page contains a trace of '£' to then hide the message. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are still wanting do to flag search but if a £ is found to hide the flag always

using jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/a4U5A/3/

```
if ($("body:contains('£')").length) {
     $('#checkout_notification_text').hide();
} else {
    //it is not found
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Perhaps I did not make this clear. This code I want to add on a separate page is irrelevant to flags - I just wanted to show you the base code I started with. Irrespective of flags, if £ is found, the message should be hidden. I am still a bit unsure of the code to put in as the updated code I tried didn't work. Many thanks.